# Can't convert a member function from type 'double (ClassOne::)()' to type 'double (ClassOne::*)()'

Tags: c++, class

I create a class and want to initialize the parameters by `generate_n` in C++.

Here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class HiddenLayer
{
public:

    double *W;
    double *b;

    ClassOne(int low, int high)
    {
        this->low = low;
        this->high = high;

        this->W = new double[100];
        this->b = new double[100];

        generate_n(W, 100, uniform);
    };

    ~ClassOne()
    {
        delete[] W;
        delete[] b;   
    };

private:
    double low;
    double high;

    double uniform() {
        return rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * (high - low) + low;
    };
};
```

And the error reported is `cannot convert ‘ClassOne::uniform’ from type ‘double (ClassOne::)()’ to type ‘double (ClassOne::*)()’`, what does the error represent?

Comment: `HiddenLayer` should be `ClassOne`.

Comment: [OT]: You may use `std::vector<double>` instead of raw owning pointer. in C++11, you may prefer facilities from `<random>`.

Comment: @remyabel you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you must use `&ClassOne::uniform` to take the address of a member function; member functions do not have implicit decay to pointers-to-member like free functions do.

However once you have made this fix you will get different errors; you can't use a member function as the functor for `generate_n`. It has to take a free function, or an object with `operator()` defined.

In C++11 (or boost::function prior to that) there is a preset functor template called `std::function` which you can create from a function-with-arguments and a given argument using `std::bind`, where member functions are treated as functions with a hidden `this` argument; the code is:

```
auto f = bind( &ClassOne::uniform, this );
generate_n(W, 100, f);
```